# Move Trigger Function from SQL Server to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I've created a working Trigger within SQL Server that increments a number within a day.
So each day starts at 1 and increments for each datarow.

With 1st select I take the Inserted Date value with.
Then 2nd select gets the max value of number field.
The 3rd query is an update to the inserted row with the new max number field value.

```
CREATE Trigger trigger ON table AFTER INSERT AS DECLARE @index INT DECLARE @from DATE

       SELECT @from = CAST(INSERTED.Date AS DATE) FROM table 
              INNER JOIN INSERTED
              ON table.Oid = INSERTED.Oid;

       SELECT @index = ISNULL(MAX(table.number), 0) + 1 FROM table 
              WHERE table.dateField >= @from AND table.dateField < DateAdd(day,1,@from);

       UPDATE table SET number = @index
              FROM table
              INNER JOIN INSERTED
              ON table.Oid = INSERTED.Oid
```

Now the Problem is that I don't get it work / written correctly for PostgreSQL.

Maybe someone can give me some jump start for Postgres to solve that problem.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html
An example trigger function is on https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: I strongly recommend against attempting to use triggers to create sequential values. If multiple sessions attempt to update the table concurrently, then it's possible for multiple rows to have the same value. There are ways to address that concern, but they all adversely affect performance and add complexity.